# Swift - UIView inside custom UITableViewCell won't update buttons/labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

I'm just getting started with Swift and I'm having some weird issues with a custom UITableViewCell. The issue is I needed to have a white background inside each table cell as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1399.jpg).

I have created a custom UITableViewCell class and created IBOutlets for a image, label and button as shown below:

```
import UIKit

class LocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var locationImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var locationButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}



override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

My view controller code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var locationTableView: UITableView!

var skiLocation = Location(name: "Banff", picture: UIImage(named: "ski.jpeg")!)
var tundraLocation = Location(name: "Yellowknife", picture: UIImage(named: "tundra.jpeg")!)
var beachLocation = Location(name: "Cancun", picture: UIImage(named: "beach.jpeg")!)
var locations: [Location] = []



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: LocationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

    cell.locationLabel.text = self.locations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.locationImageView.image = self.locations[indexPath.row].picture

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locations = [skiLocation, tundraLocation, beachLocation]
    self.locationTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I have approached this problem by making a UIView inside of each table view and then placing the button, label and image inside the UIView. This was just to get the white background. However, when I run my code everything shows as expected, except there is no UILabel and the UIButton is stylized as per storyboard. When I try to change the background of the label, or the button via storyboard, nothing changes. No label and just the generic button. The weird part is I am able to set the images to the UIImageView via the ViewController class.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Rqt.jpg) is the link to the storyboard view. I have used the identifier field in the storyboard view to link the cell.

Comment: Can you show your cell in IB?

Comment: @AlexKosyakov [Here](http://i.imgur.com/LhgvV7h.jpg) is a screenshot of my storyboard. Does this help?

Comment: I can not see, did you set constraints to the superview of your label and button?

Comment: And add tableView.reloadData() after self.locationTableView.dataSource = self

Comment: @AlexKosyakov Not sure why the screenshot isn't working? Works on my end. Yes I have constrained the button and label. The button shows up in the right location it is just completely standard. No colors or styles that I added via storyboard.

Comment: I mean did you set constraints to uiview where your label and button are

Comment: Did you try to reload tableview after setting datasource?

Comment: Yeah tried reloading, no luck. I'm pretty sure my constraints are good as the button shows up as expected it's just not stylized as I did in storyboard

Comment: Are you sure you connect you iboutlets with cell?

Comment: Figured it out! Some messed up implicit height constraints in storyboard. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have  `UITableViewDataSource` But `UITableViewDelegate`is missing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var locationTableView: UITableView!

var skiLocation = Location(name: "Banff", picture: UIImage(named: "ski.jpeg")!)
var tundraLocation = Location(name: "Yellowknife", picture: UIImage(named: "tundra.jpeg")!)
var beachLocation = Location(name: "Cancun", picture: UIImage(named: "beach.jpeg")!)
var locations: [Location] = []



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: LocationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("location", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

    cell.locationLabel.text = self.locations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.locationImageView.image = self.locations[indexPath.row].picture

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locations = [skiLocation, tundraLocation, beachLocation]
    self.locationTableView.dataSource = self
    self.locationTableView.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't using any delegate functionality so I didn't need it (yet). However I messed around a bit and I found it was some wacky implicity height constraints in storyboard.